# 805a0190 - VPN software changed my region now OS broken and No app downloads

Tags: lumia

Tried VPN software and it region changed my phone and now OS Broken in all sorts of ways and can no longer download anything from the Microsoft store. I can still do somethings, but many things are broken even after setting region back.

See here for more info: https://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/464294-805a0190-no-apps-will-download-lock-button-dead-no-data-sense.html?_ga=2.131712271.1449025656.1503932168-260380196.1493928207

No one sees to be able to solve this, besides a reset.